# Ports logged into switch

Tags: storage, storage-area-network, switch

How do I check what cellera ports are logged into my MDS 9505 series switches?
Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hello there wildchild - how do you want to do this? personally I'd be tempted to use the Fabric Manager or Device Manager GUIs, either by using DM to look at each port's FLOGI table (you do know what ports it's connected to right?) or by using FM to look at the VSAN's zoneset, on the bottom right pane is a full list of that VSAN's logged in ports. If you want to do this by CLI let me know and once again I'll look through the far-from-hidden SANOS/NX-OS command guide for you.

edit - and why the hell have you bought a 9505? couldn't you have got a much better 9222i - they're miles better, cheaper, faster - you must have a really specific reason to have bought a 9505 - whereas the 9509's I buy actually make sense.

Comment: @ chopper ...thanks . I am using 9509 .I appolozise for the typo.
However , i am unable to locate the celerra ports using show zoneset active. plz help me with the CLI..thanks in advance.

Comment: what OS is it running (exactly)?

Comment: actually just a 'show flogi database' should give you everything you need, no filtering or whatever but you'll see everything.